# Matplotlib Bar Chart - x-axis Categorical Variables changes whenever code re-runs (Numpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

i'm trying to plot a simple bar chart of the average 'resale_price' (y-axis) for each flat type against 'town' (x-axis) for data from 2015-2019. However for some reason, my x-axis keeps changing every time I re-run my code. Not sure where I've gone wrong.

dataset: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/resale-flat-prices

here's the code i've used below

```
labels1 = list(set(data_3room['town']))
town1 = np.arange(0,len(labels1))
town1_values = data_3room[['town','resale_price']]

values1 = town1_values['resale_price']/1000
# print(values1)

avg_values1 = {}

for i in labels1:
    valuesfortown1 = values1[town1_values['town']==i]
    avg1 = np.average(valuesfortown1)
    print("Average 3 Room Resale Price for town " + i + " is {:.0f}".format(avg1))
    avg_values1[i] = avg1

from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter  
avg_values1 = OrderedDict(sorted(avg_values1.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True))

plt.figure(1, figsize=(30,30))
barchart1 = plt.bar(list(avg_values1.keys()), list(avg_values1.values()), color='#d62728')

for i in range(len(barchart1)):
    bar1 = barchart1[i]
    x1,y1  = bar1.get_xy()
    h1 = bar1.get_height()
    plt.text(x1,h1,"{:.0f}".format(list(avg_values1.values())[i]),fontsize=30)

plt.title('3 Room Resale Prices by Town',fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('Resale Prices (Thousands)',fontsize=40)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(town1, labels1, fontsize=40,rotation='vertical')
```

Comment: Can you describe how it keeps changing?

Comment: I have chosen to sort it in descending order so I can quickly see which 'town' would have the highest resale price. When I first run, it was 'Bukit Batok' first followed by 'Hougang', 'Toa Payoh', 'Queenstown', 'Tampines' and so forth. But after I choose to 'Restart and run all cells', it is giving me a different order of town from before. I hope this explains

Comment: My latest run is now giving me another order - 'Queenstown', 'Bukit Merah', 'Bukit Timah', 'Marine Parade', 'Bedok' and so forth. It does not seem like my x-axis is corresponding to the y-axis value.